# The plist file at path `flutter/ios/Pods/Intercom/Intercom.xcframework/Info.plist` doesn't exist

Tags: android, ios, flutter, intercom

The plist file at path `flutter/ios/Pods/Intercom/Intercom.xcframework/Info.plist` doesn't exist.

I just added intercome to the project and at once unable to run the project for both, ios and for android.

https://pub.dev/packages/intercom_flutter

when I tried to run commant arch -x86_64 pod update I have same error in terminal